# Does Apple state which SDK version is mandatory to use for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, sdk, version, app-store-connect

Does anyone knows if there is a document from Apple that states what iOS SDK version you have to use for building your app to upload it to iTunes Connect?

I often read in blogs "only the latest", but I need this official from Apple because our vendor wants to build against the iOS 4 SDK because of "strange errors with iOS 5".

I'm not sure if this is OK. We want to run the app to run on iOS 4 and 5.

Comment: Build one for iOS4 and check it on the devices with iOS4 and iOS5. There are modern apps that require iOS3.0 or higher, so I guess you can use any to upload it to the AppStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had read what you had—that the latest SDK had to be used... Yet, I haven't found an official source for this now I go looking for it.

Using the iOS 5 SDK does not prevent you from having a build target of iOS 4.2 (or similar), which will it to run on both iOS 4.2+ as well as iOS 5. Perhaps a good starting point is educating the client that there is a fundamental difference between the iOS 5 SDK and iOS 5 itself—they may well just be reacting to media coverage of iOS 5 issues like battery life.